# Капча, при комментирование от групп

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, recaptcha, спам

Когда комментарии под пост(пользователя) идут от групп(к примеру 2х) и возникает капча, то она накладывается на какую-то из групп(которой вызвана капча впринципе), или же на пост в целом?

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то вообще капча накладывается на ip.